# Security center 'Approve as Baseline' missing

Tags: azure-security

When I look at the issues mentioned in Azure security center, I only see 'Exempt'. Where can I find the 'Approve as Baseline' option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have two options:

1. Click on the vulnerability and on the right side the resources will be listed. Clicking on the resource takes you to the page where 'Approve as Baseline' is shown
2. Another option is to the resource directly and in the security section you could find the vulnaribilities list. There you should find the option to 'Approve as Baseline'

'Exempt' usually is denied for most people in an organization. Approve as Baseline lets us track the changes.